# ADD function that will provide dynamic location and dynamic separator

Tags: vb.net

I need to add a function that will allow a dynamic position and a dynamic separator with reference to cases where the entered position deviates from the existing expressions.
I have this function:

```
Sub Main()
  GetInsideStringByIndex("a.b.c",".",1)
End sub

Function GetInsideStringByIndex(text As String, delimiter As String, index As Integer) As String
  Dim result as [String]() = text.split(delimiter)
  Return result(index)
End function
```

I don't know how to handle with the exception. This action may throw error.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't handle exception at all - leave it for the caller of the method who uses wrong arguments. You can maybe check that index exists in the result and if not retun `Nothing`

Comment: You have to check whether `String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)` (change that name, e.g., `inputString`), then the value of `index` value in relation to `result.Length`: `return If (index >=  result.Length, nothing, result(index)`. The rest is handled by the caller.

Comment: The most you should be doing in the function is basic validity checks e.g. throw `ArgumentNullException` if `text` or `delimiter` is null, and probably also throw `ArgumentException` if either string argument is empty or `index` is negative.  At that, you might want to make `index` a `UInteger` so it can't be negative.